# How to get previous value from gtk-notify-signal handler?

Tags: gtk

For example,

```
   g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "notify::title", G_CALLBACK(onTitleChanged), NULL);

void onTitleChanged(GtkWidget* widget,
                    GParamSpec* property,
                    gpointer data)
{
    g_message("%s is changed, the new value is %s\n", property->name, gtk_window_get_title(GTK_WINDOW(widget)));
}
```

How could I get the previous(old) title value inside the notify-signal handler(onTitleChanged) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not available from GObject so you'll have to cache the current value in in your app.

The safe way to do that is to update the cached value in the end of your notify handler -- but depending on your uses you may also need to initialize the value (and must of course remember to allocate/free when necessary if the value is a string).